# how to query mongodb datetime which is a object/bson?

Tags: mongodb

I set the date time as object in the mongoDb, but I can no longer query based of date time

Earlier the date time field in the mongoDb used to be a string and the queries worked fine
But now we switched the date time to object and the old queries don't work anymore. I tried using the ISODate() but nothing is being returned

old query that worked: { "classId" : "cls123", "classTime" : { "$gte" : "2019-06-01T00:00:00.000", "$lte" : "2019-08-11T00:00:00.000" } }

I tried this, which is still not working1: { "classId" : "cls123", "classTime" : { "$gte" :  ISODate("2019-06-01T00:00:00.000"), "$lte" :  ISODate("2019-08-31T00:00:00.000" )}}

2:{ "classId" : "cls123", "classTime" : { "$gte" :  new ISODate("2019-06-01T00:00:00.000"), "$lte" :  new ISODate("2019-08-31T00:00:00.000" )}}

3: { "classId" : "cls123", "classTime" : { "$gte" :  new Date("2019-06-01T00:00:00.000"), "$lte" :  new Date("2019-08-31T00:00:00.000" )}}

//nothing worked so far
here is how the date time field looks in my mongoDb

[image]

Comment: Could you post the query you used to set the data to object, please?

Comment: There is a camel job that does the insertions to mongodb, and it is inserted as localdatetime